# Second screen only displays "Check Signal Cable" after changing to new cable

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

I use a laptop and recently starting using an old monitor (932NW) as a second screen. The screen would have problems quite often, generally from bad plugging.
There are two cables involved with the computer plugging:

- A VGA-HDMI cable where the HDMI connects to the laptop and the VGA is received from the other cable
- A VGA-VGA cable, where one VGA connects to the VGA-HDMI cable and the other VGA connects to the monitor.

I was using the original cables, that were old, and usually getting the screen to successfully work involved messing with the HDMI section until it worked and then I couldn't touch it or the screen would disconnect. When disconnected that way, the screen would just be fully black and the power button's light would go on and off.
Last week the cable started working incredibly better and usually just plugging the HDMI to the laptop would make it work, instead of having to spend a while messing with the HDMI. Then a few days ago the screen would be disconnected overall (not even messing would work). I thought maybe my laptop's HDMI could have gotten damaged, but then I tested the monitor in another laptop and it also didn't work.

Because of that, I tried replacing the cables for newer ones. I could only get the VGA-VGA cable so far, so I tested with it. After that, the screen would display a moving "Check Signal Cable" with RGB squares, instead of being black until connection. The same message appears if I remove the VGA cable overall. I'm not quite sure about what's happening, so I'll list the possibilities I considered and I hope someone can answer which of these (or another one) is the most likely scenario here:

1. The black screen is an indication that the VGA is properly connected to the monitor when the HDMI isn't, and "Check Signal Cable" is an indication that the VGA isn't properly connected. So the old one having a black screen and this one having "Check Signal Cable" is a sign that the new VGA cable doesn't work properly, while the old one did
2. The new cable does work properly, the black screen was an irregularity and the "Check Signal Cable" isn't a sign that the VGA cable doesn't work
3. The VGA-HDMI is the cable that needs replacement
4. The issue is a greater technical issue and cable replacement won't fix it.

Noting that I did update firmware for the model (took a lot to find it on an official source) and I did try the "press the square with an arrow button" method, which has worked in previous situations but isn't working right now.

I'm sorry if my questioning is incoherent in some level, I'm slightly sick and it's been hard to make my thoughts make sense. I'm just scared to pay for a cable that doesn't work (if situation 1 applies) or to be missing something that could fix the problem without cable replacement (or with less cable replacement) as I can't pay for cables I don't need.

Comment: Sounds like the monitor isn’t functional if it doesn’t work with another device